# How to output the currency type next to the converted number

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am trying to get my code to output the currency type name for example EURO, YEN AND USD next to the converted number but I seem to be having trouble, any help would be appreciated.

```js
function tipCalculator() {
  var billAmt = document.getElementById("bill").value;
  var tipValue = document.getElementById("tipValue").value;


  if (billAmt === "" || tipValue == 0) {
    alert("Please Enter Value")
    return;
  }


  var total = (billAmt * tipValue);
  total = Math.round(total * 100) / 100;
  total = total.toFixed(2);
  document.getElementById("totalTip").style.display = "block";
  document.getElementById("tip").innerHTML = total;

  if (document.getElementById("USD")) {

    document.getElementById("tip").innerHTML = total + " USD";
  }

}
document.getElementById("totalTip").style.display = "none";


document.getElementById("calculate").onclick =
  function() {
    tipCalculator();
  }
```

```html
<select id="tipValue">
      <option value="">--Please choose a currency--</option>
      <option value ="1.30353" id="USD">USD</option>
      <option value ="1.16158" id="Euro">Euro</option>
      <option value ="8.75747" id="Yen">Yen</option>
      <option value ="4.98785" id="Zloty">Zloty</option>
</select>
```

Comment: add the attribute `style` to the html-element with the id `totalTip`, it can be empty. Example: `div id="totalTip" style=""> ... </div>`

Answer (score 0):

What you need to do is create an array from your currency options (USD, Euro, Yen, Zloty, etc.) and refer to that array instead of `"USD"` in the following `if` statement:

```
if(document.getElementById("USD")){
    document.getElementById("tip").innerHTML = total + " USD";
    }
```

Something like this:

```
if(document.getElementById("currency_array[]")){
    document.getElementById("tip").innerHTML = total + " currency_array[]";
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

@elbrant That still has the same problem because you need to know where you are in the array. You need to pass the id to make it dynamic. So, I would make your options into click events so it can pass its id:

```
document.getElementById("option").onclick =
  function() {
    tipCalculator(this.id);
  }
```

Don't forget to add the parameter to the function.

In the function, get rid of the if statement and do this:

```
document.getElementById("tip").innerHTML = total + this.id;
```